# Area under curve lift vs angle? Any significance?

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm looking at AOA vs Cl graphs and comparing low AR vs high AR curves. What does the area under the curve mean? Thank you

Comment: What does the integral of the Cl wrt alpha mean…

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen any significance to that area.

There certainly is significance to the derivative of that curve -- the lift curve slope.

The area would have 'units' of lift coefficient (dimensionless) times angle.  While that is certainly not a proof, looking at the units gives a clue if there will be meaning.  Consider Power vs. time -- power*time is energy -- the area under a power vs. time curve is energy.